# Bending / folding issue?

Tags: modeling

Getting issue with the folding mechanism. I want to fold or bend the bar so that it get the 90 degree angle. The mesh getting merge inside each other and to some angle its away from the screws.

[Video](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NgJgr.jpg)

[image]

[image]

Need little detail information regarding the bending or folding mechanism. How it works. Any suggestion or help. Thanks

Comment: if you're planning to animate, you need to keep in mind that the 3D cursor won't be taken into account, it's the origin that will be the axis center, so maybe you should put the origin where you want to put the axis center?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

adding to @moonboots Comment: In edit mode, select vertex, vertices, or part of the "bar" you want to be the Pivot point (internal cylinder), and then RMB: Snap vertices: Cursor To Selected.

[image]

Then in Object Mode: RMB: Set Origin: Origin to 3D Cursor.  Then your pivot point will be correct

[image]

I then did the same for your "Plane.014" connection point internal cylinder.

I then aligned the bar (origin) to the Plane.014 origin:

[image]

And then the rotation of the bar was as desired:

[image]

Here is the result:  [image]

Also consider setting the Pivot Point to Individual Origins when doing these adjustments, as the 3D Cursor may not be where you want (usually located at 0,0,0):

[image]

Comment: Perfect. Thanks.